# Incremental looping in Unix

Tags: linux, loops, for-loop, while-loop, directory

See the following

```
abc/abc/abc/101/xyz/xyz
abc/abc/abc/102/xyz/xyz
abc/abc/abc/103/xyz/xyz
.
.
abc/abc/abc/110/xyz/xyz
```

first abc is parent directoy and all other are sub directories and last sub directory contains 10 files.

i will compare 101,102 go on with a number 110 and i will process all of them

Now comes the problem
and directories are as follows.

```
abc/abc/abc/101/xyz/xyz
abc/abc/abc/102/xyz/xyz
abc/abc/abc/103/xyz/xyz
.
.

abc/abc/abc/111/xyz/xyz
abc/abc/abc/112/xyz/xyz
abc/abc/abc/113/xyz/xyz
.
.
abc/abc/abc/115/xyz/xyz
```

now i will compare with my number which is increased to 115
but i want only 111 to 115 directories and its sub-directories and files are to be processed.
but not from 101 to 115 because i have processed for 101 to 110
in one word i want to loop increamentally
if it is it possible in unix, please help me by explaining in detail.

Comment: It sounds like you want your loop index to first go from 101 to 110, and then to go from 111 to 115.  Which is the same as running from 101 to 115.  You need to give more detail as to what you are trying to do; it sounds like you just need to loop from 101 to 115 and compare the index to 110, taking the appropriate action based on that comparison.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to process 101 to 110 on the first run, and then, some time later, continue from 111 to 115? If so, either save the last value you processed (i.e. 110) in a file or variable some place, or, as you process each directory, create a hidden *dot-file* in there called say `.processed` and next time you run, skip the directories which contain such a file.

Comment: i will process 101 to 110 firstly and my directoru get updated with 5 more directories from 111 to 115 and now there are 101 to 115 directories.. now i want to process only 111 to 115 directories.